Al respecto de la expresión "Me cago en ..."
"Me cago en..." está claro que es un exabrupto, un maldecir...pero qué significado tiene en hacerlo en "Diez" (Me cago en diez), en "la leche" (Me cago en la leche).
Esa es mi pregunta, ¿porque en algo concreto "en Diez·, "en los muertos", "en la leche", en "la puta", en "el As de bastos" . ¿Diez, As de Bastos, tus muertos, la puta.....?
Gracias

De acuerdo con este sitio, sería un eufemismo para evitar la blasfemia: Me cago en Dios, o (menos probable para mí) Me cago en los diez mandamientos:

"Me cago en diez". Lo curioso de esta última expresión es su origen aparentemente religioso. Hay quien dice que se trata de una transformación que cambia la palabra "Dios" por "diez" para evitar una blasfemia bastante más malsonante. En otros casos se atribuye al término "diez" una alusión a los diez mandamientos de la religión católica.

Sería similar a usar "Gosh" en lugar de "God" en inglés.

Indeed we have many minced oaths in English there is a partial list at https://www.lutins.org/lists/minced_oaths.html

Buena respuesta. Parece bastante obvio que la alteración es para no aludir a Dios de manera blasfemante (lo de los mandamientos suena muy rebuscado)

Creo que "cagar" en español es un poco diferente a "gosh" en inglés. jajaja

Sí, los latinos somos un poco más explícitos :)

Usualmente uno tiende a decir cualquier cosa que se te venga a la mente primero. Literalmente puede ser cualquier cosa, desde la más ofensiva hasta la más tonta.
Un ejemplo de ambas sería decir:

Me cago en tus muertos


Me cago en todo


This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

Por lo general se suele poner lo que te venga a la cabeza en ese momento, puede ser lo típico, o hay gente que prefiere ser mas creativa, no hay un significado como tal concreto, es más una costumbre. A veces la gente dependiendo de la zona de España añaden alguna terminación curiosa a la expresión, por ejemplo en Asturias dicen "..en les pites de Grao" (en las gallinas de Grao, un pueblo de Asturias). Supongo que "...diez" en su momento sería una costumbre que perduró en el tiempo.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
